# Azure IoT Hub: Can't call direct method using AMQP protocol

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I've been trying to make a direct method call using the AMQP protocol. But can't make it work. I believe calling direct method is possible over AMQP if I'm not wrong. It works with MQTT though. Any clues would be much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VirtualIoTDevice
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string DeviceConnectionString = "device-connection-string";
        private const string DEVICE_ID = "device01";
        private static DeviceClient _device;

        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initializing virtual IoT device..");
            using (_device = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(DeviceConnectionString, DEVICE_ID))
            {
                await _device.OpenAsync();
                await _device.SetMethodHandlerAsync("showMessage", ShowMessage, null);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static Task<MethodResponse> ShowMessage(MethodRequest methodRequest, object userContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("***Direct message received***");
            Console.WriteLine(methodRequest.DataAsJson);

            var responsePayload = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { response = "Message shown!" }));
            return Task.FromResult(new MethodResponse(responsePayload, 200));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the command to invoke the direct method:

```
az iot hub invoke-device-method -n "iothub-name" -d "device01" --method-name "showMessage"
```

Comment: Are you using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client version 1.19.0 ?  If not, try upgrading.  The versions prior to that had some bugs that might be causing your problems.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? And yes, Direct Methods should also over AMQP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I know what your issue is: In the latest version of the SDK there was some change in regards to blocking threads. I don't know if this was an intended change or a regression.

However, in your case the `Console.ReadKey()` is somehow blocking AMQP from connecting in the first place. MQTT is not affected by this - which could indicate it might be a regression.

So, if you change `Console.ReadKey()` to for example `await Task.Delay(-1)` it works again in my test.

Comment: Thanks. 'await Task.Delay(-1)' works perfectly. I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client version 1.19.0. Couldn't find anything related to blocking calls in the release notes. If you could point me to some docs, that'd be great.

Comment: I opened a Github issue for the team to investigate https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/807